# Restful WebApi Connundrum Using VS 2013 and Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have built a WebApi, and have both Models and Controllers for each of my objects, but what I don't understand is why my Context.cs sometimes uses Controllers and sometimes Models: Please see my Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace RxSurvey.Models
{
    public class RxSurveyContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        // For more information refer to the documentation:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

        public RxSurveyContext() : base("name=RxSurveyContext")
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Check> Checks { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Definition> Definitions { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Insurer> Insurers { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Item> Items { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Line> Lines { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Survey> Surveys { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Section> Sections { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Login> Logins { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Log> Logs { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.Setting> Settings { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Models.vwRating> vwRatings { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Models.vwState> vwStates { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RxSurvey.Controllers.vwSurvey> vwSurveys { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Thank you
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Well, I worked it out. When adding classes, sometimes they are initiated as controllers and sometimes as models. Make sure you set them all to models, if that is what you want.